# JPA - Force Lazy loading for only a given query

Tags: jpa

How do i enforce lazy loading strategy just for a given NamedQuery.

for eg. Consider the below pseudo code (just to explain the case) 
I have an entity

```
@Entity
class Xyz {
 int a;
 int b;

@Fetch = EAGER
 Set<ABC> listOfItems;
}
```

In this case, we have declared listOfItems to be EAGERLY fetched.

Now suppose , I have an `NamedQuery (query="getXyz" , name="select x from Xyz x where a=?")`
For this query , i just need the result to be lazy i.e i dont want the listOfItems to be retrieved.

What are the ways by which i can acheive them ?
p.s : 
 1. I dont want to change the listOfItems to be Lazy in the Entity class
 2. I dont want to select specific fields in the query like `name="select a,b from Xyz z where a = ? "`

Thanks in advance for the suggestions

Comment: What are you going to do with the result of the NamedQuery? There might be alternatives to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @siebz0r i just want the first level fields for display . Whereas there are other displays where there is need to fetch the set .. In my case, i want to improve the performance by not eagerly fetching them. If you have any suggestions , please do share. Thanks !

Comment: I would suggest annotating the set as lazy. Why isn't this possible?

Comment: @siebz0r , already we have a huge application which is already in place and it doesn't allow me to change it to lazy since there may be some places in application which may throw lazy initialization error.
Thats the reason I was looking for something that will help my case . Do you think of any thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to fetch the `Set` eagerly you have to define it as lazy. However note that the implementation is permitted to fetch eagerly when you specify lazy.

Quoting the specification:

> public enum FetchType
>   extends java.lang.Enum
>
> Defines strategies for fetching data from the database. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that data must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY strategy hint has been specified.

If you however don't want to fetch such a `Set` I would as an alternative create a small class to fit your needs:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XYZ")
public class XyzStub
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

You can query for this using a TypedQuery:

```
EntityManager em;
//....
TypedQuery<XyzStub> q = em.createNamedQuery("select x from XyzStub x where x.a = :a", XyzStub.class)
q.setParameter("a", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EclipseLink, you can use fetch groups,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup