# Hibernate and JPA always load referenced tables

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Hibernate 4+ Spring MVC + Spring Data with JPA annotations:

```
@Entity
public class ClassOne implements Serializable{

   ......
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mapper", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<ClassTwo> element = new HashSet<ClassTwo>(0);
   //more fields
   //getters and setters
   //equals and hashcode
}

@Entity
public class ClassTwo implements Serializable{
   ......
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "CEN_CEN_CODIGO", nullable = false)
   private ClassOne classOne;
   //more fields
   //getters and setters
   //equals and hashcode
}

public interface ClassOneRepository extends CrudRepository<ClassOne, Long> {

   @Override
   @Query("select c from ClassOne c")
   public List<ClassOne> findAll();
}


@Service
public class ClassOneService {

   @Autowired
   private ClassOneRepository classOneRepository;

   @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<ClassOne> findAll() {
       return classOneRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And finally I call thie service from my @Controller

```
@Autowired
ClassOneService classOneService;
```

I expect results ONLY from ClassOne but retrieving the JOIN values with ClassTwo and all the database tree associate. Is it possible to get only values for ONE table using this schema? Is it a cache problem or Fetching not LAZY?

---

EDIT: I added the relatioship between two classes

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the code to show the full JPA configuration, for example, `ClassTwo` is not shown, what is the mapping between the two classes (`@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added @Lazy for each @ManyToOne and @OneToMany relationship. It seems that Spring Data needs Spring annotations but I supposed that just was necessary to add fetch = FetchType.LAZY. No more Eager behaviours ;).

Thanks for your responses

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Lazy "If this annotation is not present on a Component or Bean definition, eager initialization will occur". I've found the documentation about this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html

Answer (score 1):

You must have the following anotation above your `Set<ClassTwo>` or its getter:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, ...)
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#fetch()

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that simple "SELECT *" JPA query returns all eagerly fetched fields for the entity.

Please refer to: [JPA - Force Lazy loading for only a given query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960363/jpa-force-lazy-loading-for-only-a-given-query)
and http://forcedotcom.github.io/java-sdk/jpa-queries.

So my solution would be to use SessionFactory to get current session and then use "classic" method

```
return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(persistentClass).list();
```

Another possible way is to create let's say a POJO object without Set which uses the same table as **ClassOne**.